# Create "Init" and "End" SIGNAL for module in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

```
library IEEE;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 
entity struture_test is
        Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
               rst : in STD_LOGIC;
               Init  : in STD_LOGIC;
               i_ia : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
               i_ib : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
               end_s : out  std_logic;
               result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0)); 
end struture_test;

architecture Behavioral of struture_test is
    signal en_sn : std_logic := '0'; 
begin 
PROCESS (clk,rst)
    variable acc : signed (23 downto 0) ;
    variable x   : signed (35 downto 0) ; 
begin
    if (rst = '0') then
        result <= (others => '0');
        end_s  <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge (clk)) then

        if ((Init) = '1') then
            acc := signed (i_ia)*signed (i_ib);
            x   := acc * signed (i_ia);

            result <= std_logic_vector (x(23 downto 12));
            end_s  <= '1';
         else
            end_s  <= '0';
         end if;    
    end if; 
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Hi everyone
I have a project which includes some blocks. The blocks link each other through Init or End Signal. It means that The End signal of one Block is connected to Init signal of the following block.
I'm confused about that Does the above code make a good Init and a End signal ?

If I change my code and convert it into Pipelined structure to operate with the higher frequency clock. The variables convert into the signals

```
PROCESS (clk,rst)
    signal acc : signed (23 downto 0) ;
    signal x   : signed (35 downto 0) ; 
begin
    if (rst = '0') then
        result <= (others => '0');
        end_s  <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge (clk)) then

        if ((Init) = '1') then
            acc <= signed (i_ia)*signed (i_ib);
            x   <= acc * signed (i_ia);

            result <= std_logic_vector (x(23 downto 12));
            end_s  <= '1';
         else
            end_s  <= '0';
         end if;    
    end if; 
end process;
```

How to create Init and End signal in this case? The block illustrates in the picture
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea is good, but the code is wrong. In addition it has some bad coding smells.

**Basic rules:**

1. Do not use asynchronous resets.
2. You can not declare signals in processes. Process allow variable declarations; architectures allow signal declarations.
3. Each signal assignment in a clock process creates a flip-flop / delay of one clock cycle. So it's 3 clock cycles delay in total, but you `end` signal is only delayed by one cycle.
4. Do not enable pipelined operations. Use a delayed chain of valid bits.
5. Do not reset pipeline results, because underlying hardware resources like DSP (multiplication) units do not support resets.

**Changed code:**

```
library IEEE;  
use     IEEE.std_logic_1164.all; 
use     IEEE.numeric_std.all; 

entity struture_test is
  port (
    clk    : in  std_logic;
    rst    : in  std_logic;
    Init   : in  std_logic;
    i_ia   : in  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    i_ib   : in  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    end_s  : out std_logic;
    result : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)    := (others => '0');
  ); 
end entity;

architecture rtl of struture_test is
  signal ValidChain : std_logic_value(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal ia_delayed : signed(i_ia'range)          := (others => '0');
  signal acc        : signed(23 downto 0)         := (others => '0');
  signal x          : signed(35 downto 0)         := (others => '0');
begin
  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      ValidChain <= ValidChain(ValidChain'high - 1 downto ValidChain'low) & Init;

      acc        <= signed(i_ia) * signed(i_ib);
      ia_delayed <= signed(i_ia);
      x          <= acc * ia_delayed;
      result     <= std_logic_vector(x(23 downto 12));
    end if; 
  end process;

  end_s <= ValidChain(ValidChain'high);
end architecture;
```

Please note: Signal `i_ia` used in the 2nd multiplication needs to be delayed by one cycle, otherwise you would mix `ia` values from different pipeline cycles.

Comment: Thank you so much! But why do not enable pipelined operations ? I still don't understand. Because I want to create "Init" signal to enable Module to operate. According to you, what should I do?

Comment: Pipeline operations are working always. You only mark what pipeline stages contain valid data. That's why the valid is delayed as long as the operation stages. So if you feed in A and B in cycle one, you also set valid to '1'. One cycle later, the result is stored in `acc` and the matching valid is stored in `ValidChain(0)`. Again, one cycle later, the correct result is stored in `x` and the matching valid in `ValidChain(1)`.

Comment: If you feed in A1, B1 and one cycle later A2, B2, then you send in 2 valid bits in a row, which are travveling through your pipeline in a group. The module after your module will check the `end_s` signal to see, when valid data arrives regardless of how long the pipeline is.

Comment: I got it and found my problems. Thank you very much.